# Join 3 tables, sum qty from 2 different tables and Group By material name

Tags: sql, join, union-all, sql-query-store

I am having below Tables

**1. Material Unit:**

```
id | Unit_name
1  | Nos.
2  | lts
```

**2. Material Table:**

```
id | Material_name
1  | bricks
2  | Cement
```

**3. Grn Table:**

```
id | material_id | qty | unit
1  | 1           | 100 |   1
2  | 2           | 500 |   1
3  | 2           | 100 |   1
4  | 1           | 200 |   1
```

**4. Consumption table:**

```
id | material_id | qty | unit
1  | 1           | 50  |   1
2  | 2           | 100 |   1
```

Results expected is as below:

```
Material Name | Unit | Total Qty | Total Consumed Qty | Stock
Bricks        | Nos. | 300       | 50                 | 250
Cement        | Nos. | 600       | 100                | 500
```

So on above results Total Qty is to be fetched from Grn Table and Total Consumed Qty from Consumption Table and Stock is difference of both and should be Group By Material Name.

Below query where getting results for only Total Quantity and need your help to get the consumed quantity also.

I am new to SQL and did tried but stuck at this point and need help.

```
Select sm.material_name as 'Material Name', mu.unit_name as 'Unit Name' , sum(g.qty) as 'Total Qty' from grn g
JOIN material_table.sm ON g.material_id = sm.id
JOIN material_unit.mu ON g.unit = mu.id

GROUP by material_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sm.material_name as 'Material_Name', --mu.unit_name as 'Unit Name' ,
 sum(g.qty) as 'Total_Qty', sum(co.total_consumed_qty) as 'Tot_Con_Qty',
 sum(g.qty) - sum(co.total_consumed_qty) as stock
from grn g
JOIN material_table sm ON g.material_id = sm.id
JOIN material_unit mu ON g.unit = mu.id
JOIN consumption co ON co.material_id = g.material_id
GROUP by material_name
```

Is this what are you expecting? Please check the column names in the query and try.

Comment: Desired output is giving double count under Total_Qty and Tot_Con_Qty. Total_Qty for Bricks is returning 600 instead of 300, and Total_Con_Qty is returning 100 instead of 50.

Comment: Then please check your join condition, some where you are using incorrect join

Comment: JOIN conditions are exactly the same mentioned by you. I have double checked.